# Turning $_POST variables in MySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql

I trying to create a MySql Query from the $_POST values trouble is i don't want to use all the $_POST values as some are used for other things so i am trying to compare the value names against an array to see if they are actual filed in the DB then if they are create a Query string out of the names an values

this is what i have up to now

```
$i = 1;
$b = 1;

$cnt = count($_POST);

foreach ($_POST as $key => $entry)
{

$array = array('Country', 'County', 'Age', 'ect', 'ect');

foreach ($array as $arrayValue) {
    if ($arrayValue == $key) {
$b++;
        if($i == 1) {$query[] = "$key='$entry'";} 
         elseif($cnt == $b) {$query[] = "$key='$entry'";} 
           else {$query[] = "$key='$entry' AND ";}
$i++;
    }
}

}
```

I have gotten stuck now im not sure how to turn all the values out of the $QUERY array into a single string ie `$search = "country='United Kingdom' AND county ='example'"`

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Don't do it like this.  Use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query = array();
$vars = array('Country', 'County', 'Age', 'etc1', 'etc2');
foreach ($vars as $v)
{
    if (isset($_POST[$v]))
    {
        $query[] = $v.' = "'.addslashes($_POST[$v]).'"';
    }
}
$query = implode(' AND ', $query);
```

Comment: `addslashes` isn't the proper way to escape MySQL data. Use `mysql_real_escape_string`, e.g. Also, the proper delimiter in MySQL is the single quote.

Answer (score 1):

You're over complicating things for yourself. If you know what variables you want to use, simply check for them and build your query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE ";

$sql_array = array();

if(isset($_POST['A'])) { $sql_array[] = 'some_col_a = '.$_POST['A']; }
if(isset($_POST['B'])) { $sql_array[] = 'some_col_b = '.$_POST['B']; }
if(isset($_POST['C'])) { $sql_array[] = 'some_col_c = '.$_POST['C']; }

$sql .= implode(' AND ', $sql_array);
```

You'd also need to check against mysql attacks etc, but this is the pure basics.

Answer (score 1):

What am suggest is use :

A. Case Insensitive using `strtolower`

B. Sanitation using  `mysql_real_escape_string`

C. Using `in_array` for validation

D. `implode` to bring everything together

```
$_POST['Country']  = "United Kingdom" ;
$_POST['County']  = "example" ;
$array = array('Country', 'County', 'Age', 'ect', 'ect');
$query = array();

foreach ($_POST as $key => $entry)
{
    if(in_array(strtolower($key), $array) || in_array($key, $array))  
    {
        $query[] = $key . " = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$key]) . "'";

    }
}

$search = implode(" AND ", $query);
var_dump($search);
```

Output

```
string 'Country= 'United Kingdom' AND County= 'example'' (length=47)
```

Optional

```
// Optional 
// You array is inconsistent  and contains case sensitive values .. use can use this to convert them to small letters 
array_walk($array, "toLower");
function toLower(&$item, $key)
{
    $item = strtolower($item);
}
```

Comment: Why would you want case-insensitivity? You could make it so much less complicated without that, too.

Comment: Look at his array .. it contains both `Country` and `ect` i figure it is inconsistent and that might cause trouble for him in feature

Comment: And what about `$array['A']` vs `$array['a']`? PHP is case-sensitive, don't forget this!

Comment: @Botanick yes that is why am using `strtolower` .. to make sure they are the same case

Answer (score 0):

Look at [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function. You should use `' AND '` as a $glue parameter.

Answer (score 0):

PDO is going to provide you several advantages; not to mention parameterized queries. I've [created a gist](https://gist.github.com/2340119) which will give you a way to whitelist only the parameters you want, builds a SQL query and executes a parameterized PDO query.

1. Lines 08 - 18 provide you with SQL to build a scratch database/table to test this on.
2. Lines 23 - 27 handle the whitelist and where clause building (just replace ' AND ' with ' OR ' to build a an "ANY" type filter instead of an "ALL")
3. Line 41 builds the full SQL query
4. Line 50 executes the parameterized query.

Here is what the `$parameters` array would contain based on our example:

```
array(3) {
  'Country' => string(3) "USA"
  'County'  => string(6) "Nassau"
  'Age'     => string(2) "21"
}
```

The `$whereClause`:

```
string(38) "Country = ? AND County = ? AND Age = ?"
```

The `$sql`:

```
string(72) "SELECT * FROM pdo_whitelist WHERE Country = ? AND County = ? AND Age = ?"
```

The whitelist portion of the source (full source is at https://gist.github.com/2340119):

```
<?php

// whitelist parameters
$post_input = ['Country' => 'USA', 'County' => 'Nassau', 'Age' => 21, 'EscalatePriviledge' => true, 'MakeMeSuperUser' => 1];
$whitelist  = ['Country', 'County', 'Age'];
$parameters = array_map('trim', array_intersect_key($post_input, array_flip($whitelist)));
$wheres     = array_map(function($fieldName){ return "${fieldName} = ?"; }, array_keys($parameters));
$whereClause= join(' AND ', $wheres);
// you should validate and normalize here as well (see: php.net/filter_var)
```

The PDO code that handles parameterizing the query:

```
$statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute(array_values($parameters));
```

Finally, here is a summary of links for your reference:

- [gist.github.com/2340119](http://gist.github.com/2340119)
- [php.net/pdo.prepared-statements](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements)
- [php.net/filter_var](http://php.net/filter_var)